# How to comment out calls to a specific API in Java source code

Tags: java, parsing

I want to comment out all calls to an API (java.util.Logging, in my case) in my codebase. Is there a good library to accomplish this easily?
I tried Eclipse ASTParser, but that is tied to Eclipse. I am now struggling with PMD's parser. I haven't yet looked at it, but can Jackpot do this? Any other suggestions?

Comment: I am not going to make this a "real" answer, because I haven't used this for years, but you can also check out ANTLR, which has a Java grammar and good support for comments in its AST nodes. I never had much luck getting my own PMD rules to work, but I blame Eclipse integration rather than PMD itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanted to comment out this:

```
Log.doLog("Here is a" /* With a block comment to make it hard */
    + " multiline log statement"
    ); doSomethingEssential();
```

then you'd have a trickier time of it because you'd need to parse the code to some extend to know where to put the comments. I.e. you want to be able to do this:

```
// Log.doLog("Here is a" /* With a block comment to make it hard */
//     + " multiline log statement"
//     ); // Line break inserted here
doSomethingEssential();
```

It's much more trivial to do this instead:

```
if (false) Log.doLog("Here is a" /* With a block comment to make it hard */
    + " multiline log statement"
    );
```

The 'if false' part ends up being optimised out by the compiler and the Log statement won't make it to the final .class file.

That way all you need is a search/replace step in your build script that replaces all occurences of

```
"Log.doLog("
```

with either

```
"if (false) Log.doLog(" or
"if (true) Log.doLog("
```

without resorting to tricky parsing of the code.

Comment: izb, I ended up using this solution. I used sed to make this change. Thanks for taking the time to write this solution up, instead of making useless, supposedly-humorous-but-lame, mysterious comments which does not add anything to the discussion at hand. :-)

Answer (score 4):

I know this isn't what you asked for, but I just want to draw your attention to the fact that you can turn logging [OFF](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/logging/Level.html#OFF) in your configuration file.

Comment: Thanks Bill, although that functionally achieves the same, that is not what I am after. I wanted to comment out the logger.log(..) calls so that the arguments are not evaluated.

Comment: No problem.  I'm going to leave this here rather than deleting it, since others may find it useful someday.

Answer (score 0):

[sed](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sed)?  Just substitute with a commented line.  You'll need to think about the match regex to catch multiline calls.

Comment: well, it's going to have a ';' in it.

Comment: There could be a ';' in the logged string. Now you're writing a parser, worrying about escaped quote characters and regretting ever starting the task.

Comment: Oh, let's send out for a grip here, shall we?  I said it would have a ';' in it.  It's also going to have a number of other things in it.  Unless your string includes the calling sequence in which it's contained, you'll be okay.  Something like /\.info(\".*\")\.*;\.*$/ should be a start.

Answer (score 0):

You can use slf4j's jul-to-slf4j module to redirect all java.util.logging calls into slf4j, and then you can choose the slf4j-nop module to ignore all the logging statements.

Will this do, or do you REALLY need to get rid of these source lines?

Answer (score 0):

using a tool to comment out or remove all of the logging code might be a bad idea.

There might be side effect code that you don't notice:

```
while ( x > 5)
{
    // some code here
    Logger.global.finest( "X is now bigger: " + (x++) );
}
```

thats a real obvious example, but it could be very subtle with a method call or something inside the logger call.

It is probably safer to turn off the logging output, or go through the whole thing manually...

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to avoid evaluation of arguments, as you say in your comments, then I assume you have calls like:

```
logger.log("Expensive toString() operation on " + this);
```

which you want to disable ?

If that's the case, and it's scattered through your code, I'd use something like [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/) to surround all instances of the above with:

```
if (loggingEnabled) {
   ...
}
```

and set the `loggingEnabled` flag to false.